# Custom Name in Filter : File input HTMLElement

Tags: html, html-input

By using fileinput element from HTML element (HTMLInputElement), I can filter the file to take custom files, for example .pdf. In Browser window [image]

since I added ".pdf" in accepts, if I want to use a custom filter like ".mvf" it only shows mvf, is there any possible way to make a expansion for mvf ?.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<input type="file" accept=".pdf,.mvf">
```